# Can't update state from inside content array React

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of elements in a state variable in React which I want to render. They have a callback passed within them which sets some state on the component. It seems this callback runs when invoked from the child, however, the state does not get updated in the parent. The code is like this:

```
setContent(
  someFunction(res)
    .map(item =>
      <Item
        key={item.toString()}
        toggleOpen={() => {
          console.log(myState)
          setMyState(!myState)
        }}
      />
    ),
)
```

If I embed this list directly into the return JSX (i.e. I don't use my `content` state variable, then it works as expected.

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/darajava/pen/NWbRYOZ?editors=0010

EDIT: If you notice the difference between the console.log and the actual state value being displayed in the interface, you'll see that the hook is actually working. The problem was not as I described, but is actually the *component* does not receive updated state values.

Comment: state value that you are updating might be same, have you tried logging state for each item when callback is invoked? what is value of `myState` ?

Comment: try this `setMyState(prevVal =>!prevVal)`

Comment: @shubhamjha I added a codepen. antoineso, I tried that, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @antoineso That solves it in the codepen, but not in my real code and I don't know why.

Comment: I will have a check

Comment: You have to `return` the last line in your function else it will always return undefined. Otherwise, you may have to use explicit return.

Comment: I have managed to reproduce it properly now in the codepen.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to return something from the `toggleOpen` like so, otherwise it'll return undefined.

```
setContent(
  someFunction(res)
    .map(item =>
      <Item
        key={item.toString()}
        toggleOpen={() => {
          console.log(myState)
          return setMyState(!myState) // or {() => setMyState(!myState)
        }}
      />
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

add `content` in useEffect dependencies :

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setContent(
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(ordersOpen)

        return setOrdersOpen(x => !x)
          }}
        >
          hi
        </div>
    )
  }, [content])
```

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/a-soros/pen/ExNgRJa)

Comment: Why doesn't this cause an infinite loop? I will try this in my real code later, but looks good.